# Stopping select.change from posting back

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, postback

this problem is part of a bigger page but I've simplified the code to provide an easy example of what I'm talking about.  Basically I have an ASP dropdownlist with AutoPostBack="true" and I want to do some javascript client side which can stop the postback if necessary.  However, I can't get it to stop the postback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#ddl").bind('change', function() {
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<select id="ddl" onchange="form.submit()">
    <option value="">Item 1</option>
    <option value="">Item 2</option>
    <option value="">Item 3</option>
    <option value="">Item 4</option>
    <option value="">Item 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my workaround (Firefox works, IE 7/8 works):

```
$(function() {
    var $select = $('#ddl'), tmp = $select.attr('onchange');

    $select.attr('onchange', '');

    $select.change(function() {
        // If you want to postback:
        tmp();
    });
});
```

Simple removes the HTML handler and puts it into a variable.  Then you can register your change function and if you want to call the auto postback function you can.

Comment: Other people have submitted something similar but I went with this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ddl').attr('onchange', '').change(function() {
    if (0 !== +$(this).attr('selectedIndex')) {
      this.form.submit();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes this will overwrite the form.submit embedded in the tag but I need to catch the onChange event and then if certain criteria aren't met, not let the page proceed with a PostBack.

Comment: @rpf3: Ahh, sorry I missed that. Does the updated snippet closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: That is, thanks, but I posted a more detailed explanation of the problem on patrick dw's answer

Comment: Heh... new attempt. It will block a submit() if the select has an empty value, otherwise it goes through.  Edit: updated again to explicitly check the selectedIndex, rather than the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ddl").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Doing `e.preventDefault()` wouldn't actually do anything more to prevent the form from submitting than the `return false;`.

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#ddl").change(function() {
    // Do some javascript
    return false;
});
```

Also, it might help if you take the onChange attribute off the select element

Comment: Your code example is effectively the same as the code in the question.